# How to delete a page after displaying it in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have one window and I switch pages in it like that:

```
win.Content = new Page1();
....
....
\* somewhere in another function *\
....
win.Content = new Page2();
```

But the other page, `Page1`, is still running (in my case, it still sends messages to the server).

How can I delete the page after I change the content of the window? 
I want that only the page that in the window content will run.

Comment: is there any timer or something running on the other page which sends the message to server?

Comment: Yes, I have an additional thread that sends messages every second to the server.

Comment: Why don't you do a cleanup on your Page1's Datacontext such as stopping the thread to send messages?

Comment: I thought that it happens automatically, if not, if I delete the page it will stop the thread automatically not?

Comment: Ok, I stop the thread to send messages and now it's work good, but still, do I need to delete the page if I don't use it or the garbage collection will delete it?

Comment: As soon as your object goes out of scope, garbage collector releases the memory, so no need to explicitly doing it.

Comment: @HiteshMistry ok, thank you!